# Какой знак поставить перед прямой речью?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое:

Я подошел к ней и, качаясь, сказал словами книги Бытие, 24:43

— [собственно цитата в виде прямой речи персонажа]

Что поставить перед прямой речью? Двоеточие? Как-то странно смотрятся два двоеточия в данном случае.

Автор настаивает на написании цифрами, а не словами.

Answer (score 3):

Для начала -  здравствуйте. Одно двоеточие к другому не имеет никакого отношения. В крайнем случае можно цифры взять в скобки: ...словами книги Бытие (24:43):...

Comment: Здравствуйте.
Большое спасибо за ответ.